# What mime types does FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE support

Tags: php

Where can i find a link that gives me a list of file types supported by [Fileinfo](http://php.net/manual/en/fileinfo.constants.php).

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow

Comment: The ones it's configured to support.  There is no definitive answer because the database can be configured very differently from one machine to another

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The list of types supported by Fileinfo is dependent on your system (server running your application).

If you use [finfo_open()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-open.php) with no parameter for `magic_file`:

> If not specified, the MAGIC environment variable is used. If the environment variable isn't set, then PHP's bundled magic database will be used.

If you do use the `magic_file` parameter, than you have to look in that file you are passing for this parameter.

The path where this magic_file is on your server, is unfortunatelly not standard, you'll have to google it yourself ;)